# How do I show all group headers in Access 2007 reports?

Tags: ms-access, report, grouping, relationship

This is a question about Reports in Access 2007.
I'm unsure whether the solution will involve any programming, but hopefully someone will be able to help me.

I have a report which lists all records from a particular table (call it A), and groups them by their associated record in a related table (call it B). I use the 'group headers' to add the information from table-B into the report.

The problem occurs when I filter the records from table-A that are shown in the report. If I filter out all table-A records that relate to a particular record (call it X) in table-B, the report no longer shows the record-X group header.

As a possible workaround, I have tried to ensure that I have one empty record in table-A for each of the records in table-B. That way I can specify NOT to filter out these empty records. However, the outcome is ugly one-record-high blank spaces at the start of each group in the report.

Does anyone know of an alternative solution?

**EDIT:**

For clarity, I should highlight what I hope to achieve. 
For records in table-B that are not linked to any records in the filtered table-A, the group header (and footer) for these records will not appear in the report. I am trying to change this, so that the group header and footer appears immeiately after each other (since there are obviously no records to put in the group body).

Comment: Why do you want to show a header without any detail records?

Comment: To simplify the scenario, the headers I'm using contain details about particular projects, and the records listed below them describe changes to the projects. The data is filtered by the report so that only changes made in the last month are shown. As you can see, if no changes were made to a given project, the project details will not be listed on the report. However, I need all ongoing projects to be listed on the report, regardless of whether or not they've been changed.

Comment: Readers should note that I have proceeded with the aforementioned workaround and I am happy with the result. I am no longer in need for an answer to this question, but I will keep this question open for the sake of others who may have a similar problem.